# Best Storage Method

Tags: char, byte, storage, file-storage

So I'm in the process of making a 2D sandbox tile based game like [Terraria](http://www.terraria.org/). I already know how to generate massive worlds like it however I'm stumped on how to store the world. I know that I should store the raw bytes to keep the file size small. I was thinking about making each tile have it's own byte however I don't know how to do this. I do know that one ASCII character is a single byte so hey why not make each tile a different ASCII character? Like have grass be 'G', dirt be 'D', and stone be 'S'. Then I could store each of the characters into a file and call it a day. I wan't to know if this method would be ok or if there is a better one?

Then assuming the previous method is ok I also need to know if .NET chars and bytes play nicely together. What I mean by that is if I convert a simple ASCII character such a 'G' for a grass tile into a byte will that be a single byte or will it be more? Maybe .NET stores a char as something bigger than a byte I don't know.

Bottom line what's the best way to store each tile type into a file? Keep in mind these worlds will be gigantic so it's a must that the file is small.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with .NET specifics, but if you use chars and store the world as a giant ascii string, it will depend on how it is stored on disk. That may make it simpler to convert from the single-byte to the character code you're using.

Secondly you will need to chunk the data or you will have difficulty loading a particular part of it, like trying to find a track on an old vinyl record.

As for the concept, you should use static classes for each tile type. This way the system does not duplicate the class-related data for thousands of single-byte objects. The byte value then is a reference to a stack containing all of those static objects.

If this seems like an esoteric secret, it's not; this is considered the proper way in OO programming to implement a deck of cards. Since the cards don't really contain many accidents or unique properties (they may have a position or an orientation, but that can be stored in the slot in the game you're building) all the cards in any game can consist of 52 card objects that are static and all decks / tableaus / stacks are merely arrays of references to these static objects.

Hope this helps you with the concepts, and good luck!